# Add jquery reference to JSlink file

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, jsom, jslink

I am using JSLink feature of SharePoint 2013, My JSLink file has code to get current user id and other details, for this I need to add reference of jQuery file.

I tried adding those files in in JSLink on edit page web part section separated by semicolon, but that didn't work.

In short, I need way where in I can reference the library files for JSLink code similar to script tag in html file.

Comment: You can get the current user id using `_spPageContextInfo` object. what other details you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding script tags for other JavaScript files in your code, you can set JavaScript files in JS Link propery by `|` separated. Please see below example:

```
JSLink="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/jQuery.js|~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/my-custom-field.js"
```

Here, it will first load `jQuery.js` and then `my-custom-field.js` in page.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I was separating the files by semicolon, thanks